# Keeping your right to an object but delaying your purchase

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-kiddushin

The reason behind the idea of עני מהפך (קידושין נט עמוד א) is a argued (תוס רש״י). The רמ״א explains that in a case of buying and selling the only time there is a case of עני מהפך is when both sides have agreed and all that's left to be done is the קנין
 (רמ״א שולחן עורך ח״מ רלז ס״א).

**My question**: let's say the עני had the chance to purchase the item by decided he rather do it later (Seller says he's ready to sell and עני says he needs more time. The seller does not care to postpone like the עני). Is this still a case of עני מהפך or can one peruse the item since the עני clearly doesn't care about or need the item that badly that I could be hurting his finances (Rashis reason for עני מהפך).

Possible case: עני wants to buy an apartment from the Seller. The Seller says (To the עני whose Infront of him) alright I'm ready to sell it to you. All the עני has left is to do the קנין. The עני responds that he needs more time.

Does the fact that he says he needs more time mean that there's more then the קנין left or maybe that's all that's left he's just posponing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `The רמ״א explains that in a case of buying and selling the only time there is a case of עני מהפך is when both sides have agreed and all that's left to be done is the קנין`

The source of the RMA is in Mordechai perek Chezkat Habatim (quoted in Bet Yosef).

> כתב המרדכי פרק חזקת בשם הר"מ ...  ובלוקח מישראל נמי לא מיקרי מהפך בחררה אלא היכא דגמרו הפיסוק כבר הלוקח והמוכר ונתרצו זה לזה ולא היו חסרים רק הקנין
>
> Mordechai wrote in name of Rabbi Meir (from Rottenburg): Even for a buyer from a Jewish The case is called "ani hamehapech bacharara" only when the buyer and the seller fixed the price and decided to make this transaction together.

I assume that this rule is true regardless of the Machloket Rashi and Tosfot. There is no case of ani hamehapech if the object is not clearly available for the ani.

> `let's say the עני had the chance to purchase the item by decided he rather do it later.`

#### Case I

the seller and the ani decided together to to make but to  postpone the transaction.

> `Is this still a case of עני מהפך or can one peruse the item since the עני clearly doesn't care about or need the item that badly that I could be hurting his finances (Rashis reason for עני מהפך).`

Maybe an other lecture on Rashi. See how the  Bach explained it.

> ופירש דנקט עני לאורויי דאפילו בהפקר או מתנה נמי נקרא רשע והא דנקרא רשע לפי שיורד לחיי חברו
>
> Rashi wants to expain the expression עני Gemara told about a poor man so that we can apply the din to hefker (Metsia) or to a gift (as a cake).  He wants alsto warrant the   word  רשע . Because cake for a poor is obviously a gift or a Metsia  and because a rich man does not need a cake for survival.  Rasha is only for a case of  "יורד לחייו" . But in a case of selling as the case of Rav Gidel,  there is no  "יורד לחייו"., and Rashi is aware to the fact that the din apply.  Your case is not a Metsia so Rabenu Tam agrees with the din ani hamehapech...

Thus,  by the way, the din apply even if the transaction is delayed.

---

#### Case II

The OP was edited and asked especially for this case.

> `The case is where the עני delays but the seller does not. The seller is ready and wants to sell.`

**According to the Mordechai above quoted this  case is not a case of Ani hamehapech bacharara.**  because they the seller did not commit to delay the transaction.

Comment: The case is where the עני delays but the seller does not. The seller is ready and wants to sell. I thought that was clear when I specified the עני delays but I apologize for not being clear

Comment: @huddie96 You can edit your question to clarify as long as it doesn't invalidate existing upvoted answers. Thus, at the moment, you can. (And it would probably be wise to).

Comment: An edit was just submitted before there were any upvoted answers.

Comment: @Double AA  I think that my answer is  good for the edit too

Comment: @huddie96 I modified the answer according to your clarification.

Comment: @kouty could you edit in the explanation of the mordechai and why that proves it's not עני מהפך

Comment: @huddie96 see the new edit

Comment: @kouty Just out of curiosity, in a hypothetical third case where the עני delays and the seller although he's ready to sell now, doesn't really care when he sells the item just that he sells it. What the conclusion be?

Comment: @kouty also reading the mordechi it appears he's called a רשע, is that true?

Comment: @huddie96 If note preliminarly that the sin of ani hamehapech is a special sin of the second buyer.  For the seller there is others sins: mekayem et devaro; mi shepara etc following the cases.  Here for the second buy there is no problem because he doesn't break any accord which was reached by the first buyer

Comment: @kouty Right I'm focused on the second buyer specifically. The third case I mentioned. He would be over ani hamehapech? called a rasha? Or nothing?

Comment: @huddie96 who is called rasha?

Comment: @kouty The second buyer would be called a Rasha in certain cases I believe.

Comment: @huggie96 nothing absolutely because he has not canceled any thing already reached by the first buyer

Comment: In case 1 @huddieoy